# ShowMessage not showing in Delphi DLL called from C++

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I want to call this delphi code via a DLL from C++

```
procedure MyMessage; stdcall;
begin
  ShowMessage(DLLName + ' more text');
end;
```

Using some delphi test code I see no problem , but from C++ no message box is shown.

i did the following C++ coding

```
//  function prototype 
typedef void(__stdcall*VoidCall)(); 

//  prototype for info function inside DLL 
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall MyMessage();


MyMessage = (VoidCall)::GetProcAddress(load, "MyMessage");

MyMessage;
```

As I want to use as a next steps existing delphi forms with a wrapper DLL from C++ , I guess the solution of this problem will also enable me for the next  task ....

Comment: When asking questions, please present fully working and compiling code snippets. See [How to create a good sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presented C++ code does not compile. It mixes binding of a dll via an import library with dynamic loading of a dll via `LoadLibrary` / `GetProcAddress`.

To load a DLL created with Delphi, it is easiest to use dynamic loading of the dll. Do this as follows:

```
//  function prototype 
typedef void(__stdcall*VoidCall)();
```

[...]

```
// Load the library
HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary("Project1.dll");
if (lib != 0)
{
    __try
    {
        // Get the address to the exported function in the DLL
        // and store it in the variable myMessageFunction
        VoidCall myMessageFunction = (VoidCall) GetProcAddress(lib, "MyMessage");

        // Call the function. Note you need the parenthesis even
        // when there are no parameters to pass
        myMessageFunction();
    }
    __finally
    {
        // Unload the library again. Note that you cannot use 
        // functions from the library after that. So only unload
        // the dll once you don't need it anymore.
        FreeLibrary(lib);
    }
}
else // TODO: Error handling, dll cannot be loaded
```

---

If you want to use load time linking, you can create a *.lib file to be used with C++ for a DLL created with Delphi. Use the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175301/using-delphi-library-in-c).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Answer adapted

Comment: compile and  use of several function inside that dll is working fine;   I guess message box (DELPHI CODE : ShowMessage (..)   ) is not connected to my form that why I don't see  anything ....

Comment: Your code `MyMessage` withouth parenthesis does not call the method. Is this really your code? If yes, then try to add the parenthesis? If not, show us your real code.

Comment: after adding  parenthesis ti the function call, problem has been solved !  thanks for this helping answer